# FPGA Simple RAM Model - Why is the address delayed?

Tags: fpga, vhdl, verilog

In the sample code below from [Doulos](https://www.doulos.com/knowhow/vhdl_designers_guide/models/simple_ram_model/) that models RAM using an array, why is the address delayed?

Specifically, why did they bother to create a second signal `read_address` instead of using the input `address` throughout to access the array?

I suspect it has something to do with concurrent versus sequential, but I can't figure it out...

---

```
-- Simple generic RAM Model
--
-- +-----------------------------+
-- |    Copyright 2008 DOULOS    |
-- |   designer :  JK            |
-- +-----------------------------+

library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;
use IEEE.Numeric_Std.all;

entity sync_ram is
  port (
    clock   : in  std_logic;
    we      : in  std_logic;
    address : in  std_logic_vector;
    datain  : in  std_logic_vector;
    dataout : out std_logic_vector
  );
end entity sync_ram;

architecture RTL of sync_ram is

   type ram_type is array (0 to (2**address'length)-1) of std_logic_vector(datain'range);
   signal ram : ram_type;
   signal read_address : std_logic_vector(address'range);

begin

  RamProc: process(clock) is

  begin
    if rising_edge(clock) then
      if we = '1' then
        ram(to_integer(unsigned(address))) <= datain;
      end if;
      read_address <= address;
    end if;
  end process RamProc;

  dataout <= ram(to_integer(unsigned(read_address)));

end architecture RTL;
```

Answer (score 4):

It is a **write-first** (write-before-read) RAM, so the address is delayed to see the new value at `dataout` port. If `dataout` was delayed, we would see the old value at `dataout` port and it would become a **read-first** RAM.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, block RAM in FPGAs is synchronous, hence something has to be registered (either address in or data out) in order for the RAM to be properly inferred. Sometimes you even have to register both if you want to get very high performance, otherwise the block RAM clock to output delay can really cause trouble. Distributed RAM, on the other hand, is usually asynchronous and hence does not need to be implemented this way.